# Change file/folder tree structure based on name condition

Tags: python, path, shutil

I've a folder/file tree like this:

```
/source/photos/d831fae7-ed7f-44b1-8345-54fc54f0710f/car/1.jpg
/source/photos/20a33e40-8bb2-4ebe-b703-632115ba6714/house/
/source/photos/20a33e40-8bb2-4ebe-b703-632115ba6714/boat/b6a1b8bf-7f4c-45d6-84c1-37fbb8204328/2.jpg
/source/20dd7963-0d4a-4a80-83f8-4800de672087/music/1.mp3
/source/64e997aa-bb7e-4cdf-9348-8b8d48e2d336/music/c6a0b1d4-9d2d-4a21-bce3-8c922f8ad55b/2.mp3
/source/movies/83e760f4-7235-4d7e-bd51-56aa82192a94/572f3820-ea22-40c1-903a-31b7f412ae38/1.mp4
/source/movies/993209ed-092a-4665-a5d1-4ce537e2a680/4c200cf1-eb6b-40a7-84d7-9a2db0f75e09/1.mp4
```

To easily read the previous tree, here it is a simpler representation:

```
/source/photos/uuid0/car/1.jpg
/source/photos/uuid1/house/
/source/photos/uuid1/boat/uuid2/2.jpg
/source/uuid3/music/1.mp3
/source/uuid4/music/uuid5/2.mp3
/source/movies/uuid6/uuid7/1.mp4
/source/movies/uuid8/uuid9/1.mp4
```

---

I want to move the folders and files from "`source`" to the "`destination`" directory and perform a tweak in the tree structure on the fly. The resulting tree should look like this:

```
/destination/photos/car/1.jpg
/destination/photos/house/
/destination/photos/boat/2.jpg
/destination/music/1.mp3
/destination/music/2.mp3
/destination/movies/1_1.mp4
/destination/movies/1_2.mp4
```

---

As you can see, I want to:

- Ignore every `uuid` in the middle of the path;
- When there is a conflict on file or folder name (i.e. `1.mp4`), an incremental suffix should be added (i.e. `1_1.mp4`);
- Move empty folders (like "`house`");
- Avoid conflicts when moving (moving a parent directory before moving its child) - it should **recursively** trespass the tree and move its contents.

I've tried parsing the path with `os.walk` but can't accomplish this.

---

Any ideas? Thanks!

---

**NOTE:** `uuid` (i.e. `6e56c11b-3adf-440e-96f5-375884c96c55`) can be checked using the following function:

```
import uuid
def validate_uuid4(uuid_string):
    try:
        val = uuid.UUID(uuid_string, version=4)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True
```

---

**EDIT: Example code**

The main problem is this:

Given the following structure

```
.
├── Icon\r
└── folder1
    ├── d.txt
    └── folder1.1
        ├── 64e997aa-bb7e-4cdf-9348-8b8d48e2d336
        │   └── a.mkv
        └── d831fae7-ed7f-44b1-8345-54fc54f0710f
            ├── b.mkv
            └── d831fae7-ed7f-44b1-8345-54fc54f0710f
                ├── b.mkv
                └── c.jpg
```

with this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import uuid

args = {}
args['rootdirOriginal'] = "/Users/xxx/Desktop/UploadDropbox"
pathString = []
pathStringClean=[]

def validate_uuid4(uuid_string):
    try:
        val = uuid.UUID(uuid_string, version=4)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True


for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(args['rootdirOriginal']):
    if files:
        for f in files:
            pathTmp = []
            pathRelative = os.path.relpath(dirpath, args['rootdirOriginal'])
            for p in pathRelative.split("/"): 
                pathTmp.append(p)
            pathTmp.append(f)   

            pathTmpClean = [x for x in pathTmp if not validate_uuid4(x) and x[0] != "." and x[0:4]!="Icon"]

            pathStringTmp = ("/").join(pathTmp)
            pathStringTmpClean = ("/").join(pathTmpClean)

            if len(pathTmp) > 0:
                pathString.append(pathStringTmp)
                pathStringClean.append(pathStringTmpClean)

print pathString
print pathStringClean
```

this is the first output:

```
['./.DS_Store', './Icon\r', 'folder1/.DS_Store', 'folder1/d.txt', 'folder1/folder1.1/.DS_Store', 'folder1/folder1.1/64e997aa-bb7e-4cdf-9348-8b8d48e2d336/.DS_Store', 'folder1/folder1.1/64e997aa-bb7e-4cdf-9348-8b8d48e2d336/a.mkv', 'folder1/folder1.1/d831fae7-ed7f-44b1-8345-54fc54f0710f/.DS_Store', 'folder1/folder1.1/d831fae7-ed7f-44b1-8345-54fc54f0710f/b.mkv', 'folder1/folder1.1/d831fae7-ed7f-44b1-8345-54fc54f0710f/d831fae7-ed7f-44b1-8345-54fc54f0710f/b.mkv', 'folder1/folder1.1/d831fae7-ed7f-44b1-8345-54fc54f0710f/d831fae7-ed7f-44b1-8345-54fc54f0710f/c.jpg']
```

and this is the second:

```
['', '', 'folder1', 'folder1/d.txt', 'folder1/folder1.1', 'folder1/folder1.1', 'folder1/folder1.1/a.mkv', 'folder1/folder1.1', 'folder1/folder1.1/b.mkv', 'folder1/folder1.1/b.mkv', 'folder1/folder1.1/c.jpg']
```

I can't just remove the duplicates since some times they are not truly dups but, instead, should be renamed as I described before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my ending solution (thank you Sushanta!)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import uuid
from collections import Counter
import shutil

args = {}
args['rootdirOriginal'] = "/Users/xxx/Desktop/UploadDropbox"
args['uuid'] = str(uuid.uuid4())
args['rootdir'] = args['rootdirOriginal']+"/"+args['uuid']

pathString = []
pathStringClean=[]
pathStringFolder = []
toDelete = []


# Validate if string is a valid UUID
def validate_uuid4(uuid_string):
    try:
        val = uuid.UUID(uuid_string, version=4)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True


# Walk through "source" directory
for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(args['rootdirOriginal']):
    # Files
    if files:
        for f in files:
            pathTmp = []
            pathFolderTmp = []
            pathRelative = os.path.relpath(dirpath, args['rootdirOriginal'])

            for p in pathRelative.split("/"): 
                pathTmp.append(p)
                pathFolderTmp.append(p)

            # Flag every fuke   
            pathTmp.append(f+"***") 

            # Delete list elements whose name are:  a previous UUID //// starting with "." //// starting with  "Icon"
            pathTmpClean = [x for x in pathTmp if not validate_uuid4(x) and x[0] != "." and x[0:4]!="Icon"]
            pathFolderTmpClean = [x for x in pathFolderTmp if not validate_uuid4(x) and x[0] != "." and x[0:4]!="Icon"]

            # Convert to path string
            if len(pathTmpClean) > 0:
                pathStringTmp = ("/").join(pathTmp)
                pathStringTmpFolder = ("/").join(pathFolderTmpClean)
                pathStringTmpClean = ("/").join(pathTmpClean)
                pathString.append(pathStringTmp)
                pathStringClean.append(pathStringTmpClean)
                if pathStringTmpFolder != "":
                    pathStringFolder.append(pathStringTmpFolder)

    # Empty directory               
    if dirs:
        for d in dirs:
            emptyDir = os.path.relpath(dirpath, args['rootdirOriginal'])
            if emptyDir == ".":
                emptyDir = d
            else:
                emptyDir =  os.path.join(emptyDir,d)

            pathStringFolder.append(emptyDir)

# Delete repeating directories          
pathStringFolder = list(set(pathStringFolder))

# Create a list with the indexes of first list when it is a directory 
for i in range(0,len(pathStringClean)):
    if (len(pathStringClean[i]) > 3):
        if pathStringClean[i][-3:] != "***":
            toDelete.append(i)

# Delete indexes of both "source" and "destinantion" lists where it is directory
for i in sorted(toDelete, reverse=True):
    del pathString[i]
    del pathStringClean[i]

# Delete the flag "***"
pathString = [x[:-3] for x in pathString]
pathStringClean = [x[:-3] for x in pathStringClean]

# Rename repeated filenames - create sequential suffix
counts = Counter(pathStringClean)
for s,num in counts.items():
    if num > 1:
        for suffix in range(1, num + 1):
            pathStringClean[pathStringClean.index(s)] = ("/").join(s.split("/")[:-1]) +("/")+(".").join((s.split("/")[-1]).split(".")[:-1])+"_"+str(suffix)+"."+(s.split("/")[-1]).split(".")[-1]

pathStringFolder.reverse()

# Create root "destination" directory
os.mkdir(args['rootdir'])

# Create other directories 
for folder in pathStringFolder:
    try:
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(args['rootdir'],folder))
    except:
        pass

# Move files
for i in range(0,len(pathStringClean)):
    os.rename(os.path.join(args['rootdirOriginal'],pathString[i]),os.path.join(args['rootdir'],pathStringClean[i]))

# Delete everything except root "destination" directory
for f in os.listdir(args['rootdirOriginal']):
    if (not (os.path.isfile(os.path.join( args['rootdirOriginal'],f))) and f != args['uuid']):                  
        shutil.rmtree(os.path.join( args['rootdirOriginal'],f))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the time to give a full implementation, there are a lot of ways to do this as well, but here is an outline, which may provide you with a start.
Your question isn't very specific either unless you want a full solution handed to you, i.e. what specific problems you are running into and so on, but here goes:

```
import os
from sets import Set

def remove_uuids_from_path(path):
    # implement a function to remove uuids from the path name
    # use os.path.split or os.path.splitdrive and validate_uuid function
    # to build new paths without uuids

# build a set of source paths to work on
# or you can attempt to create the new path here
# and move files, as the file names are there in files list
source_paths = Set()
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source_dir):
    source_paths.add(root)
    # edit: if you want file paths do:
    for file_name in files:
        file_name_path = os.path.join(root, file)

# run through source paths, replace source name with destination name
for s_path in source_paths:
  new_path = remove_uuids_from_path(s_path.replace(source_name,    destination_name))
  # create new directory if it doesn't allready exist
  if not os.path.exists(new_path):
      os.makedirs(new_path)
  # read file names from source directory into a list
  # move files to new directory if they don't exists there allready, else employ naming scheme.
  for new_path_to_file in file_name_list:
    if new_path_to_file.is_file():
        # change name by inspecting destination files names
    else:
       # move/copy file
```

Comment: the problem with the first function is that I'll get multiple paths with the same name (["a","a","a/b","a/b","a/b/c/1.jpg"]

Comment: the function which removes the uuids from the paths will not return unique paths, this is true. You need to test if path exists before creating. Then you attempt to move files, and if the names are already in use you need to employ some naming scheme for destination files.

Comment: I would suggest creating the destination directory structure before moving files, as you specified you want to move empty directories? That being said, if you only want the paths to actual files then this will print them all out: `for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        for file in files:
            print os.path.join(root, file)`

Comment: I added the file path example as an edit to my original reply, sorry for multiple edits.